# Extract strings with unique characters from javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to extract only those strings which have unique characters, I have an array of strings:

```
var arr = ["abb", "abc", "abcdb", "aea", "bbb", "ego"];
Output: ["abc", "ego"]
```

I tried to achieve it using Array.forEach() method:

```js
var arr = ["abb", "abc", "abcdb", "aea", "bbb", "ego"];
const filterUnique = (arr) => {
  var result = [];
  arr.forEach(element => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
      var a = element[i];
      if (element.indexOf(a, i + 1) > -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    result.push(element);
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(filterUnique(arr));
```

Want to know is any other way to achieve this task ?

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd `.filter` by whether the size of a Set of the string is the same as the length of the string:

```js
const filterUnique = arr => arr
  .filter(str => new Set(str).size === str.length);
console.log(filterUnique(["abb", "abc", "abcdb", "aea", "bbb", "ego"]));
```

(a Set will not hold duplicate elements, so, eg, if 4 elements are put into a set and 2 are duplicates of others, the resulting size of the Set will be 2)

Answer (score 2):

You can check by creating sets from strings also, a `Set` object will always have unique values.

```js
var a = ["abb", "abc", "abcdb", "aea", "bbb", "ego"];

console.log(a.filter(v => v.length === new Set(v).size))
```

Comment: I didnt know Set would break down the string, thanks for pointing out